# How can I use ref for another component?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a sidebar with list of items, and when I click on an item, it should scroll to a certain div, which are outside components. Sidebar looks like this:

[image]

Sidebar component:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
    const [sideBar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
        <span class="btn" onClick={() => setSidebar(!sideBar)}>Menu</span>
            <div className="profile">
                <img src={spike}/>
                <span>Alim Budaev</span>
                <span>Available for work</span>
            </div>
            <ul className="sidebarlist" id={sideBar ? "hidden" : ""}>
            {SlidebarData.map((val,key) =>{
                return (
                <li 
                    className="row"
                    id={window.location.pathname === val.link ? "active" : ""}
                    key={key} 
                    onClick={()=> {
                        
                    }}>
                    {""}
                    <div>
                        {val.title}
                    </div>
                    </li>
                );
            })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Components in App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header">
        <Sidebar/>
        <Hero">
            <Particles/>
        </Hero>
      <About/>
      <Service/>
      <Form/>
      <Footer/>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So I'm looking to way to scroll to a certain component when I click on

. I know it can be made through useRef(), but I don't know how to do it in the Sidebar with outside components.

Comment: If I get you correctly, you want a page to scroll to view after click on the nav item?

Comment: yeah! to be particular, not a page, but a component, cause I have only one page, and it consists of multiple big components that come one after another, so i have to scroll into view a component when i click on the nav item

Comment: There is another approach you use for this, make all your pages/component `position:absolute`,`transform:translateY()` out of view  then on click of each nav item add a class that restores the page back to view.
something like this: https://dellysn.github.io/portfolio/#

Comment: If you can give a unique id (for instance matching the component name) to each component  you want to scroll to, you can just simply use this `onClick` handler in your menu items: `onClick={() => document.getElementById(val.title).scrollIntoView()}`. You can see a simple example in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-bassi-7sxn6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @tromgy hello! what if my components are in another files instead of in App.js. Cause I have the navbar in Sidebar.jsx file, so should I import all the components there?

Comment: @tromgy anyway, your answer helped me, thank you so much!